# Showing $\sum^\infty \frac{\log{(n^2 + 2)}}{n^2 + 1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need this to show the analogous function has improper integral (since it decreases). I've checked that both ratio and root tests are inconclusive ($=1$), so I was trying to use a comparison, but I couldn't come up any useful inequalities besides $\log(x) \leq \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$, which didn't help.

Any help, especially hints, is appreciated.

Comment: The summand is $o(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$ so it converges by Riemann's criterion since $\frac32 > 1$ (using the fact that $\log(n^2) = 2 \log(n) = o(\sqrt{n})$)

Comment: @Evariste Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *asymptotic equivalence*:
a polynomial is equivalent to its leading term, so $n^2+2\sim_\infty n^2$ and $n^2+1\sim_\infty n^2$. Therefore
$$\frac{\log (n^2 + 2)}{n^2 + 1}\sim_\infty \frac{\log(n^2) }{n^2}=1\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2},$$
and it is well-known that a *Bertrand's series*:
$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{n^\alpha\ln^\beta n}$$
converges if & only if $\alpha >1$ or [$\alpha=1$ **and** $\beta>1$].

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{\frac{\log{(n^2 + 2)}}{n^2 + 1}}{\frac 1{n^\frac 3 2}}=\frac{\log{(n^2 + 2)}}{\sqrt n + \frac 1{n^\frac 3 2}} \to 0$$

therefore the given series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1{n^\frac 3 2}$.